# How do I count exoplanets per system in a file with over 10,000 lines in Python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text, logic

I am working with astronomical data and I need help summarizing it.

My data contains ~10,000 lines, where each line represents a system.

The input file is tab delimited like this:
exo sys_planet_count

```
0   1   
0   0   
3   4   
0   1   
2   5   
0   0
```

Note that exo planet count is usually 0 or 1, but NOT Always.

**Each line represents a system** and there are two columns, one for the exo_planets found in that system and one for the total number of planets found.

I need the data summarized like this by increasing sys_planet_count:

system_planet_count exo system_hits system_misses

```
5 3500 3000 1000
6 4500 4000 1500
```

The **number of exo planets must be greater or equal than system_hits**, because there could be only one exo planet per system or several, it depends.

system_planet_count is how the the table is organized.

For each line (system) that matches a particular system_planet_count, it adds the number of exos found. 
If there were exos found, it adds +1 to the system_hits category because that line found exo planets, a hit. 
If there were NO exos found in that line, it adds one to the system_misses category because there were no lines in a planet.

NOTE that system_misses and system_hits category is specific to that system_planet count, i.e. 3000 and 1000 for system_planet_count of 5 but 4000 and 1500 for a system_planet_count of 6

The problem is that the data is NOT ordered in ascending order of sys_planet_counts.

To summarize the data, I came up with the following code. What should I do to summarize the data in a quick manner that doesn't take 10 or 15 minutes?

I was thinking about using a dictionary, since each system_planet_count could act as key

```
while open('data.txt','r') as input:
    for line in input:
        system_planet_count = 0
        exo_count = 0
        system_hits = 0
        system_misses = 0

        foo
    output.write(str(system_planet_count) + '\t' + str(exo_count) + '\t' + str(system_hits) + '\t' + str(system_misses) + '\')
```

Input example:

exo sys_planet_count

```
 2 1
 0 1
 1 1
 0 5
 1 5
 0 5
 0 5
 2 5
 0 5
 0 4
```

Output:

system_planet_count exo system_hits system_misses

```
 1 3 2 1
 4 0 0 1
 5 3 2 4
```

Comment: One little question: must not the number of exos (col 2 of summary) be necessarily greater or equal to the number of hits? Everytime you add 1 hit, you add 1 or more exos...

Comment: Not necessarily @schwobaseggl . It only happened in this particular data. I'll edit that. The **number of exo planets must be greater or equal than system_hits**, because there could be only one exo planet per system or several, it depends.

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited the post and added an example input and output file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the summary you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def summarize(file_name):
    exo, hit, miss = 0, 1, 2  # indexes of according counts
    d = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0, 0])  # keep all counts for each type of system
    with open(file_name, 'r') as input:
        for line in input:
            exos, planets = map(int, line.strip().split())  # split, cast to int
            if exos:
                d[planets][exo] += exos
                d[planets][hit] += 1
            else:
                d[planets][miss] += 1

    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        print('{} {} {} {}'.format(key, d[key][exo], d[key][hit], d[key][miss]))

summarize('data.txt')
```

Comment: This worked! I have to run some data sets to confirm it, but I think we have winner.